# how to calculate the sum of grades for each student

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have one table for the grades of exams, and another for students (the students table will always have 10 students only).

I want to output an array in Json format for students details with the sum of grades of each by semester in array of array.

**expected output**

```
[
    {
    "id": "1", -> this is the semester ID
    "student1": {"id": "1","name": "student name", "bio": "50", "chem": "50", "math": "60", "total grades": "160"},
    "student2": {"id": "2","name": "secondstudent name", "bio": "60", "chem": "60", "math": "50", "total grades": "170"},
    }
]
```

here is my tables structure

**tbStudents**

```
   id   ,    name                
    1   ,    student name        
    2   ,    secondstudent name 
    3   ,    thirdstudent name
```

**tbGrades**

```
    id   ,  student   ,  semster    ,   bio    ,   chem    ,   math   ,  total
     1   ,     1      ,     1       ,   50     ,    50     ,   60     ,   160
     2   ,     2      ,     1       ,   30     ,    40     ,   20     ,   90
     3   ,     2      ,     1       ,   30     ,    20     ,   30     ,   80
```

**challenge**

How to calculate the SUM of each bio, chem, math, total for each student by semester, cause the student might have multiple grades in the same semester

**what i've tried**

```
$sql = "SELECT grade.id g_id, grade.semester g_semester, grade.bio g_bio, grade.chem g_chem, grade.math g_math, grade.total g_total, student.id s_id, student.name s_name FROM tbGrades AS grade INNER JOIN tbStudents AS student ON student.id = grade.student";

try {
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    $grade = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $db = null;

    if(empty($grade)) {
        $response->getBody()->write
        ('
        {
            "error":
            {
                "status":"400",
                "message":"Invalid Request"
            }
        }');
    } else {
         foreach($grade as $value) {
            $array_resp[]=[
                'id' => $value->g_id,
                'student1' => ['id'=>$value->s_id, 'name'=>$value->s_name, 'bio'=>$value->g_bio, 'chem'=>$value->g_chem, 'math'=>$value->g_math, 'total grades'=>$value->g_total],
             ];
        }
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($array_resp));
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $response->getBody()->write
    ('
    {
        "error":
        {
            "message":'. $e->getMessage() .'
        }
    }');
}
```

Comment: Your table design is flawed. A normalised grades tables might have 5 columns, one of which would be `subject`

Comment: Agree with @Strawberry, if this is learning, fine, but if long-term development for final, fix your table structures now or you will hate yourself later.

Comment: can you show me how the table structure should be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using MySQL [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) clause.

```
SELECT 
grade.id g_id, 
grade.semester g_semester, 
SUM(grade.bio) g_bio, 
SUM(grade.chem) g_chem, 
SUM(grade.math) g_math, 
SUM(grade.total) g_total, 
student.id s_id, 
student.name s_name
FROM 
tbGrades AS grade 
INNER JOIN 
tbStudents AS student 
ON 
student.id = grade.student
GROUP BY
student.id, 
grade.semester
```